# Writing data structure with char* and std::list to binary files

Tags: c++, file, stream, binary

I am trying to write a data structure as such:

```
struct dataEntry
{
    std::list<int> listTiles;
    char* pData;
    int nSize;
}
```

to a binary file.

I used ofstream to write to a binary file:

```
Write(char* fileName, const dataEntry& dataStruct)
{
    ofstream binFile("fileName, ios::out |      ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    if(binFile.open())
    {
        binFile.write((char*)&dataStruct,     sizeof(dataStruct));
        binFile.close();
    }
}
```

I used the same method to read back the binary file:

```
Read(char* fileName, const dataEntry& dataStruct)
    { 
        ifstream binFile("fileName, ios::in|      ios::binary );
        if(binFile.open())
        {
            binFile.read((char*)&dataStruct,         sizeof(dataStruct));
            binFile.close();
        }
    }
```

However, i cannot iterate through the list after i read the binary file. It gave me an exception saying that the "list iterator outside range".

2nd problem is that when i tried to read the binary file the 2nd time, the "pData" is not what I have entered.

```
int Main()
{
    char* name = "C:\\file.dat";
    char* buf = "ABCDEFG";
    dataEntry newData;
    newData.listTiles.push_back(1);
    newData.listTiles.push_back(2);
    newData.nSize = 5;
    newData.pData = buf;
    Write(name, newData);



    Read(name, newData);
    buf = newData.pData; // wrong value when read 2nd time
    newData.listTiles.remove(2); // crashed here       
}
```

Comment: Open the file you wrote in an editor.  Do you see anything in the file that looks like the data?  I bet not.  So given that, how did you expect to turn "junk" back into an object?  The problem is that you should be saving the *data* that your class represents, not a pointer value and certainly not a bunch of bytes representing a `list` object.  Google "object serialization".

Comment: So you are saying that i should be saving the list values itself(1,2) instead of the list object?

Comment: Yes, you save the data in some set, coherent manner so that you know how to "reverse the process" when recreating the object.  Also, you will note that regardless of the number of items in your linked list, this: `sizeof(dataStruct)` never changes.  you could have no items in the linked list, or a million items, the `sizeof(dataStruct)` stays the same.  Again confirming that your method has no way of working correctly.

Comment: I see. So for the 2nd problem, i assumed, i had convert the char* to char array and write it to the file?

Comment: The pointer points to a string.  Again, you save the *data*, not the pointer.  A pointer is useless outside the scope of the running program.  So you save (for example) `0xa6718bee`.  How does that represent a string when you want to read it back?  That certainly doesn't look like "ABCDEFG" to me.

Comment: There is no need to convert.  Just write the buffer that the pointer points to.  You probably also need to write the number of bytes the string takes up, as you have to know when to stop reading when recreating the string.  Again, what you should end up with is a file that when you view it, you understand what the data in the file represents.  If you got a file that looks totally unrelated to the data you're saving, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Kai This may be relevant: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Check advanced c++ course on Udemy, the instructor said you cannot store pointers to binary files, because when you try to read them back the pointers (addresses) you used before writing them will not still be reserved for the list. So you have to save the data not the pointers